how to pre compile AJV standalone validation code when you have custom keywords?
I am trying to generate pre compile standalone code like so:
https://ajv.js.org/standalone.html
I have an AJV instance created like so:
  const ajv = require("ajv");
  const add_formats = require("ajv-formats");
  const add_errors = require("ajv-errors");
  const ajv_inst = new ajv({
    code: { source: true }, // needed for standalone pre compiled scripts
    allErrors: true,
    $data: true,
  });
  add_errors(add_formats(ajv_inst));

However, I have custom keywords defined like so:
  ajv_inst.addKeyword({
    keyword: "custom_array",
    validate: (schema, data) => {
      try {
        const unique_name = data.map((tar) => {
          return tar.name.toLowerCase().replaceAll(/\s+/g, "");
        });
        const unique_id = data.map((tar) => {
          return tar._id;
        });
        return (
          new Set(unique_name).size === data.length &&
          new Set(unique_id).size === data.length
        );
      } catch (err) {
        return false;
      }
    },
    metaSchema: {
      enum: [true],
    },
  });

In order to generate the standalone code with custom keywords, I think the keyword needs to be defined with a code generator function instead of the validate like so:
  code(cxt: KeywordCxt) {
    const {data, schema} = cxt
    const op = schema ? _`!==` : _`===`
    cxt.fail(_`${data} %2 ${op} 0`) // ... the only code change needed is to use `cxt.fail$data` here
  },

https://ajv.js.org/keywords.html#define-keyword-with-validate-function
questions:

Given that I already have the validate property defined, is there a way to generate the pre compiled standalone code with the function defined as is in the validate property?
If not, is there an easy or automated way to convert my validate function into the required code-gen code?

